# How to get data from 2 rows which has same data in all columns except one in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As in my title I want to take data from 2 rows but In my case each 2nd row has one different value compare to the first row.

I want to take all the common data along with the different data as a single row .

Here you can see each row has same values in another row except the 2nd rows last column.

[image]

Thanks.

Edits Result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a some kind of ordering *columns*  that could specify your actual data ordering if so, then you can use `row_number()` function

```
select * from (
   select *,
           row_number() over (partition by <common data cols> order by ? desc) Seq  
   from table t
) t
where seq = 1;
```

**EDIT :**  I don't believe your `inventort_item_id` columns but yes you could use `creation_date` for ordering purpose

```
SELECT 
       EPI.ITEM_CODE, LMP.PROD_DESC, LLPC.COLOC_PROD_PRICE,
       BASE_PATH + '' + EPI.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + EPI.IMAGE_DESCRIPTION AS POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS 
FROM (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_CODE ORDER BY creation_date DESC) as Seq 
      FROM ECOM_PRODUCT_IMAGES EPI
     ) EPI
INNER JOIN ECOM_POPULAR_PRODUCTS_MAPPING EPPIM ON EPPIM.ITEM_CODE = EPI.ITEM_CODE
INNER JOIN LOM_MST_PRODUCT LMP ON LMP.PROD_CODE = EPI.ITEM_CODE 
INNER JOIN LOM_LNK_PROD_COMP LLPC ON LLPC.COLOC_PROD_CODE = LMP.PROD_CODE
WHERE EPI.Seq = 1 AND 
      EPPIM.ITEM_STATUS = 'ACTIVE';
```

**EDIT 2:** In that case you need to use `GROUP BY` clause  with *conditional* aggregation

```
SELECT 
         EPI.ITEM_CODE, LMP.PROD_DESC, LLPC.COLOC_PROD_PRICE,
         MAX(CASE WHEN EPI.Seq = 2 
                  THEN (BASE_PATH + '' + EPI.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + EPI.IMAGE_DESCRIPTION) 
             END) AS POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS,
         MAX(CASE WHEN EPI.Seq = 1
                  THEN (BASE_PATH + '' + EPI.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + EPI.IMAGE_DESCRIPTION) 
             END) AS PATH_NEW
FROM (SELECT *,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_CODE ORDER BY creation_date DESC) as Seq 
      FROM ECOM_PRODUCT_IMAGES EPI
     ) EPI
INNER JOIN ECOM_POPULAR_PRODUCTS_MAPPING EPPIM ON EPPIM.ITEM_CODE = EPI.ITEM_CODE
INNER JOIN LOM_MST_PRODUCT LMP ON LMP.PROD_CODE = EPI.ITEM_CODE 
INNER JOIN LOM_LNK_PROD_COMP LLPC ON LLPC.COLOC_PROD_CODE = LMP.PROD_CODE
WHERE EPPIM.ITEM_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY EPI.ITEM_CODE, LMP.PROD_DESC, LLPC.COLOC_PROD_PRICE;
```

Comment: Can you please guide me in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933734/how-to-merge-two-rows-which-has-same-data-in-all-columns-except-one-in-mssql

Comment: @Nikson... Can you show us what are columns in table `ECOM_PRODUCT_IMAGES ` ??

Comment: I have updated the columns in this post please take a look on it

Comment: @Nikson... Use `creation_date` cols as for ordering purpose and use analytical function check edited.

Comment: Yogesh Sharma , Please see the result I got after applying your edited suggestion,It returns only the 2nd image path and missed the 1st image path

Comment: it returns only the row which has the different data in the POPULAR_PRODUCT_IMAGE_PATH column but I want the data of POPULAR_PRODUCT_IMAGE_PATH column from both rows

Comment: Is it possible to get ,Please guide me to get solve this issue

Comment: @Nikson... Now i understand your issue. So, tell one thing What if one item code has 2 or more image path ? How would you display them ?

Comment: When I hover on the one Image It will show another Image of the same product for that I need to have 2 images for a single product.
That's why every product has two rows in database and have different image paths for same product

Comment: Thanks a lot ,Can you please explain this to me .

Comment: @Nikson... This is a  conditional aggregation  that could be achieve via `GROUP BY` or using `PIVOT`. So, for more you can search on SO by typing `conditional aggregation` or `pivoting`.

Answer (score 1):

here is my approach, also using a window function.

sample data

```
if object_id('tempdb..#x') is not null drop table #x
CREATE TABLE #x (ITEM_CODE VARCHAR(10), PROD_DESC VARCHAR(20), 
                COLOR_PROD_PRICE DECIMAL, POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO #X(ITEM_CODE,PROD_DESC,COLOR_PROD_PRICE,POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS) VALUES
('P0001', 'Axe Brand', 88.000, 'some_path_to_img1.jpg'),
('P0001', 'Axe Brand', 88.000, 'some_path_to_img2.jpg'),
('P0002', 'Almond Nuts', 499.000, 'some_path_to_img1.jpg'),
('P0002', 'Almond Nuts', 499.000, 'some_path_to_img2.jpg')
```

query - just change #x to your table and it should work

```
;WITH my_cte as
(
    SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM_CODE ORDER BY POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS) AS 'track_row'
    FROM #x 

)

SELECT a.ITEM_CODE, a.PROD_DESC, a.COLOR_PROD_PRICE,
        a.POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS + ' ' + b.POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS AS 'POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS'
FROM my_cte AS a
     INNER JOIN
     my_cte AS b ON a.ITEM_CODE=b.ITEM_CODE
WHERE a.track_row=1 AND b.track_row=2
```

output

```
ITEM_CODE   PROD_DESC   COLOR_PROD_PRICE    POPULAR_PRODUCTS_IMAGE_PATHS
P0001      Axe Brand    88                 some_path_to_img1.jpg some_path_to_img2.jpg
P0002      Almond Nuts  499                some_path_to_img1.jpg some_path_to_img2.jpg
```

Comment: Please guide me through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933734/how-to-merge-two-rows-which-has-same-data-in-all-columns-except-one-in-mssql